# Serialize DataTable using protobuf-net-data gives Method Not Found error

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

I have been using the protobuf-net-data library (Richard Dingwall and Arjen Post) to serialize datatable. This was working fine and I was busy with something else. Recently I got back to this project, but I am getting error:

```
Method not found: 'Void ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter..ctor(System.IO.Stream, ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext)'.
```

I took the source code and compiled as a separate library and tried to debug. Getting same error. In the `DataSerializerEngine` class, trying to enter the Writer.Serialize gives error.

```
public void Serialize(Stream stream, IDataReader reader, ProtoDataWriterOptions options)    
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
    }

    if (reader == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
    }

    Writer.Serialize(stream, reader, options);
}
```

I tried using older version of protobuf-net (2.3.2), but same issue. Not sure why I am getting this error. Much appreciate any help.

**Latest update** - After Marc's comments below: the latest version of protobuf-net-data was still using the ctor. I changed from using new to Create. With that, I am able to serialize. I took the protobuf-net-data src code and am making changes locally.
Now I am getting problem in DeSerialize (below 3065 was length of byte string sent after serialization of data table):

```
Sub-message not read entirely; expected -3, was 3065

   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.State.ThrowProtoException(String message) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Core/ProtoReader.State.ReadMethods.cs:line 764
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.State.EndSubItem(SubItemToken token) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Core/ProtoReader.State.ReadMethods.cs:line 514
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.EndSubItem(SubItemToken token, ProtoReader reader) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Core/ProtoReader.cs:line 288
   at ProtoBuf.Data.Internal.ProtoReaderContext.EndSubItem()
```

When I tried to use latest version of protobuf-net, the Create is deprecated as Marc mentioned. Some methods take writer as a parameter, so I am not sure how to change the code using State APIs.

regards

Comment: Are you seeing this at runtime? Or in the compiler? And have you treble checked what version of the library you're shipping? The ProtoWriter constructor did change in V3, but that has been flagged in the library with a warning via [Obsolete] for literally years (there's a static creation method that works identically in current V2 and V3). This sounds like it should be a 1 line change in whatever additional library you're using, to use that static creation method rather than the constructor.

Comment: Found the commit that added the warning to use Create: July 2018: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/75da66b5ad27db5b5b6a09cd0ee18b580fa38b23 - but importantly: the constructor *still exists* (and will always exist) in any V2 version of the library. This makes me conclude that you're actually deploying a V3 version of the protobuf-net library (which lacks the constructor)

Comment: Hi Marc - Thanks for the quick reply. Please see the Update above. After changing to ProtoWriter.Create, I am able to serialize. But deserialize now fails.
And is there any change in your protobuf-net so it directly supports data tables?

Comment: "fails" isn't enough for me to do anything with; what actually happens? The choice to not try to support DataTable is deliberate, and I have no plans to try to add it - there are too many ways to get into a mess, and it simply isn't a great fit for protobuf generally. If 3rd party libraries want to add that: great,  but I can't necessarily opine when there are problems

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc. I finally decided to switch to using BinaryFormatter for serialization (and from there to Protobuf ByteString). I was facing further issues that I could not not figure out. I discovered that the protobuf-net-data library worked fine when called from a normal console app but gave the errors listed in my original post when called from a grpc server app. I just did not want to spend more time on this. Totally understand what you are saying though.